# How to know whether NSTableView is in editing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, editing

I want to check if my NSTableView is in editing or not.

I tried to use **tableView: shouldEditTableColumn: row:** and **tableView: setObjectValue: forTableColumn: row:** functions. For example:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
     isRenaming = YES;
     return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
     isRenaming = NO;

     ...

}
```

However, **tableView: shouldEditTableColumn: row:** function was called even when I didn't try to edit the tableview.

So, sometimes, isRenaming is remained to YES.

How to know whether NSTableView is in editing?

Comment: Why don't you just use setObjectValue method?

Comment: What do you mean? @Parag Bafna

Comment: - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
         isRenaming = YES;
    
         ...isRenaming = NO;
    
    }

Comment: setObjectValue: function is called after the cell is edited. So, it's not what I want.

Comment: "in editing" means that the textfield is appeared and you can type a new value for the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the missing case.

"**tableView: shouldEditTableColumn: row:**" function was called when the double-click event was occured on NSTableView.

So,

```
- (void)tableViewDoubleClicked:(id)sender {
       isRenamed = NO;
       ...
}
```

It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set your view controller to be a delegate for the text view in your table view cell.

Then you can set "`isRenaming = YES`" when the user triggers the [`[control: textShouldBeginEditing:]` protocol method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control%3atextShouldBeginEditing%3a).  You can also set "`isRenaming = NO`" when the user is done editing (or when they click the "done" or "save changes" button in your UI).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to implement - "Set your view controller to be a delegate for the text view in your table view cell."? There is no delegate in NSTextFieldCell.

Comment: Try returning a NSTextField instead of a NSTextFieldCell and see if that works, to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check `edited​Row`?

```
let isBeingEdited = yourTable.edited​Row != -1
```

> This property does not apply to view-based table views. In a view-based table view, the views are responsible for their own editing behavior. For other tables, the value reflects the index of the row being edited or –1 when there is no editing session in progress.